# Getting segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, encryption

My program has to encrypt/decrypt the textfile but I'm getting `segmentation fault(core dumped)` when I do this:

```
./program 9999 input.txt output.txt
```

The program takes every character from the `input` file and converts it based on the passed `key`. It compiles fine when I compile in CodeBlocks and does not give any errors. Could smb tell me what's wrong with the code? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


//Checks if the input arguments are less than 2 (starting from 0)
//A user should enter 3 arguments so as not to reach this method
int badProgram(const char *const program){
    printf("The program is missing some of the files!");
    return -1;
}

//Encrypts the passed inputFile and
//Produces its output to the passed outputFile
//Key is also passed as the seeding number
int encryptFile(FILE *input, FILE *output){
    char c;
    char p;
    int r = 0;
    char p1 = 0;
    char c1 = 0;

    while((p = fgetc(input)) != EOF){
        r = rand() % 97;
        //change all displayable characters [0...96]
        if(p == 't'){
            p1 = 0;
        }
        else if(p == '\n'){
            p1 = 1;
        }
        else{
            p1 = p - 30;
        }

        c1 = p1 ^ r;//bitwise xor
        if(c1 == 0){
            c = 't';
        }
        else if(c1 == 1){
            c = '\n';
        }
        else{
            c = c1 + 30;
        }
        //Write
        fprintf(output, "%c", c);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Check the number of the entered arguments
    if(argc < 2){
        return badProgram(argv[0]);
    }
    else{
        FILE *input;
        FILE *output;

        //Seed a number into Random Generator
        int key = *argv[0];
        srand(key);
        input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        encryptFile(input, output);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `**input.txt**` looks like this:

```
Hello, World!

Bye!
```

Comment: post also input.txt contents and your debugger message

Comment: use a **debugger** - it will be able to "tell you what's wrong with your code"

Comment: @YePhIcK, but how should I use a debugger when I'm passing args from command line?

Comment: check return value of `fopen`.

Comment: And use `fputc(c, output);` instead of `fprintf(output, "%c", c);`, just think about it, `fprintf()` needs to parse the format and then get the approrpiate parameter and the probably call `fputc(c, output);`, so why don't *you* call it directly?.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, what's wrong with it though :) ?

Comment: how does this work : `int key = *argv[0];`

Comment: @KemalP. If `fopen` returns `NULL`, it will cause a segment fault in the function that uses it. YePhIcK pointed out `fopen(argv[1], "r");` => `fopen("9999", "r");`

Comment: Different IDEs have different ways of debugging programs so "how to debug if I pass arguments from command line" really depends on the debugger you are using. In the most primitive case you can "just" hardcode those values at the beginning of your `main` (granted that in this *particular* case that would not have helped you much)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things that are wrong with your code:

- `int key = *argv[0];` is most likely not doing what you think it does. What it **actually** does is the following:

  > assign an ASCII value of the first character of the `[0]` argument (program name) to an int variable
  >   It is likely that what you intended to do there is:

  `int key = atoi(argv[1]);  // this converts "9999" into an int 9999`
- `input = fopen(argv[1], "r");` opens a file named (in your case) "9999" for reading and fails. You **never** check for the error so this is causing a crash the moment you are trying to use the `input` `FILE` pointer. The fix is to use the `argv[2]`
- Similarly you should be using `argv[3]` for the output file
- Your `encryptFile` function **must** return a value as it is declared `int` (don't know why you want to return a value from it as you never use it)

Once you fix the above issues your program no longer crashes

**Update**

A bit of explanation for the above issues and general info:

- The `argv` lists all the input parameters as strings (`char*`) where the first (`[0]`) argument is the *executable name* and is not your first argument "after" the program name
- One should **always** check the results of file operations as they are quite likely to fail during "normal" program operation
- C/C++ doesn't "automatically" convert a string into an `int` (or a `double`, for that matter) but provides a whole set of functions to deal with numbers' parsing. Some examples of those functions are: 'atoi', 'atol', 'atof'

Comment: Does argv[0] always points to the name of the program then? @YePhlcK

Comment: Absolutely always, guaranteed by the language standard

Comment: THANKS A TONS! @YePhlcK Thanks for the clear explanation! I'm still learning C and still having problems with its syntax. Hopefully, will over it! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank me by using debugger ;-)

Comment: :) Btw, did you use CodeBlock's debugger (because it's somehow disabled in mine and it does not allow me to use)? Or some different ide? @YePhIcK